# Why is Quiet sometimes ineffective in parallel kernels?

Tags: parallelization

I was trying to suppress some warnings while evaluating code in parallel and noticed that [`Quiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) appears to be completely ineffective for some messages only.  Using [`Off`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html)/[`On`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/On.html) does seem to work, but I have to disable the messages in both the sub-kernels and the main kernel.

## Working Example

Here's an example where `Quiet` works exactly as expected:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Quiet[0 / 0]]
```

## Non-working Example

An example where `Quiet` does not work:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Quiet[NIntegrate[x, {y, 0, 1}]]]
```

Interestingly, not only are the error messages *not* suppressed, but each kernel produces the same error message many times (I counted 15 per kernel after disabling `General::stop`).  Furthermore, the main kernel also produces another 6 error messages, when it shouldn't be evaluating the integral in the first place.

Running the same code on the main kernel produces no error messages, and even removing `Quiet` only results in one message appearing.

As an alternative to `Quiet`, I can use `Off` in the sub-kernels which does remove the messages from the sub-kernels:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Off[NIntegrate::inumr]];
ParallelEvaluate[NIntegrate[x, {y, 0, 1}]]
ParallelEvaluate[On[NIntegrate::inumr]];
```

However I still get a 6 error messages from the main kernel which I thought would not be evaluating the integral.

I can silence everything with an additional `Off` in the main kernel but I think this just hides the unnecessary evaluations in the main kernel.

```
Off[NIntegrate::inumr];
ParallelEvaluate[Off[NIntegrate::inumr]];
ParallelEvaluate[NIntegrate[x, {y, 0, 1}]]
On[NIntegrate::inumr];
ParallelEvaluate[On[NIntegrate::inumr]];
```

---

### Edit

Thanks to the reply from @Szabolcs, I am able to reduce the number of error messages to just one per kernel and no error messages from the main kernel with:

```
ParallelEvaluate[
 NIntegrate[x, {y, 0, 1}] /. NIntegrate -> Inactive[NIntegrate]
]
```

As @Szabolcs mentions, the error causes `NIntegrate` to be returned in its original form (instead of `Inderetminate[]` or `$Aborted`), and the main kernel tries to evaluate it (again) when it receives it from the sub-kernel.  Interestingly, the above hack also fixes the multiple error messages, so it would seem like `NIntegrate` gets passed around several times within the sub-kernel.

Now the question would be whether this has any negative impact on `NIntegrate`.  Although the above case was always going to fail, I wonder whether the `NIntegrate` gets passed around is to handle difficult integral (e.g. due to slow convergence, zero integral, etc.).

Comment: I don't know why the subkernels produce the error message multiple times. The reason why the main kernel does is that some Mathematica functions return unevaluated when an error occurs. This unevaluated form is returned to the main kernel, where it is evaluated again. I suspect that the reason why the subkernels show multiple errors is also related to this (and likely a bug), but I don't see how this can happen, and I cannot reproduce it with a small toy example.

Comment: Here's a toy example which shows why the main kernel also produces errors. This toy example does not produce multiple errors on the subkernels though. `foo::pos = "x must be positive";
foo[x_] := 
 Module[{}, If[Not@Positive[x], Message[foo::pos]]; 
  Sqrt[x] /; Positive[x]]` Now try `ParallelEvaluate[foo[-1]]`

Comment: The reason for the main kernel evaluating the expression again makes sense, though I feel like it really ought not to by default.  Knowing this, I can prevent this by using `Inactive`: `ParallelEvaluate[foo[-1] /. {foo -> Inactive[foo]}]`.